# How to fix my Regex pattern to get 3 blocks of values

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I have 2 kind of lines to break for 3 groups with single regex

```
line1 = """NAME1;address;10461;427144.70;012020;244312:countername1::244312:countername2::244312:countername3::[!]:1:service1:410630.15:62:penny:16514.55:;1;"""

line2 = """NAME2;ADDRESS2;10458;1853.12;012020;[!]:1:service1:1853.12:62:penny:0.00:;1;"""

my_regex1 = r'^(?P<acc>.+;.+;.+;.+;.+);(?P<counters>.*:?.*):\[\!\]:(?P<services>.*):;1;$'

my_regex2 = r'^(?P<acc>.+;.+;.+;.+;.+);(?P<counters>.*:){0,}:?\[\!\]:(?P<services>.*):;1;$'
```

Result of the first regexp on line1 like lines is ok, bit it fails on line2 like lines

```
    re.findall(my_regex1, line1) >>> 
[('NAME1;address;10461;427144.70;012020',     '244312:countername1::244312:countername2::244312:countername3:', '1:service1:410630.15:62:penny:16514.55')]
```

but it does not catch line2 at all

2nd regex breaks line 2 but fails withs counters block on line1

```
    re.findall(my_regex2, line2) >>> [('NAME2;ADDRESS2;10458;1853.12;012020', '', '1:service1:1853.12:62:penny:0.00')] #which s ok, but it fails with line2

re.findall(my_regex2, line1)

 >>>
    [('NAME1;address;10461;427144.70;012020','244312:countername1::244312:countername2::244312:countername3::','1:service1:410630.15:62:penny:16514.55')]
```

i need to fix regex2 so it could break all lines correctly, now it fails with adding unwanted ":" character to the end of block
 block of counters may not exist at all or have more than 9 fields, but block of services will always exist but can be any len

Comment: Please ecplain in detail what the desired outcome is

Comment: desired outcome is almost like my_regex2 does, but without extra ":" at the end  of counters block on line2.

Comment: Explain in Human words what are the conditions you want to split your string. I could be that you created a bad regex and it needs to be clear what you want to accomplish.

Comment: @Dmitriy Try it like this `^(?P<acc>[^\r\n;]+(?:;[^\r\n;]+){4});(?:(?P<counters>.+?:):)?\[\!\]:(?P<services>.*):;1;$` See https://regex101.com/r/8vmN1I/1

Comment: Or, `^(?P<acc>(?:[^;]+;){4}[^;]+);(?:(?P<counters>.*?):)?\[!]:(?P<services>.*):;1;$` (almost the same, [demo](https://regex101.com/r/LyUfFq/1))

Comment: string contains at the start 5 field with accounts data (?P<acc>.+;.+;.+;.+;.+) with seperator = ";", at the end of account data we see also ";" sign. than begins block with counters data which may be present or not, it ends with "[!]:" sign, if block of counters exists at the end of it we will see additional ":" like we see on  line1

Comment: @Thefourthbird thank you ! it worked!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your regex also worked!! thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the second double quote in the counters group, you might update the pattern to match the first `:` in the counters group and match the second after it directly following the group.

Note that `.+;` will first match until the end of the line and could be written using a negated character class `[^\r\n;]+;` matching any char except a `;` or a newline to prevent crossing linebreaks.

```
^(?P<acc>[^\r\n;]+(?:;[^\r\n;]+){4});(?:(?P<counters>.+?:):)?\[\!]:(?P<services>.*):;1;$
```

In parts

- `^` Start of string
- `(?P<acc>` Named group `acc`

  - `[^\r\n;]+` Match 1+ times any char except a newline or `;`
  - `(?:;[^\r\n;]+){4}` Repeat 4 times matching `;` and 1+ times any char except `;` or a newline
- `);` Close group and match `;`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?P<counters>.+?:):` Named group `counters` (Match the second `:`) after the group
- `)?` Close group and make it optional
- `\[\!]:` Match `[!]:`
- `(?P<services>.*)` Named group `services`, match 0+ times any char except a newline
- `:;1;` Match literally
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jtXswJ/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
answer1 = "^(?P<acc>[^\r\n;]+(?:;[^\r\n;]+){4});(?:(?P<counters>.+?:):)?\[\!\]:(?P<services>.*):;1;$"
answer2 = "^(?P<acc>(?:[^;]+;){4}[^;]+);(?:(?P<counters>.*?):)?\[!]:(?P<services>.*):;1;$"
```